# CSS3 "Lifted Corners" Drop-Shadow with Opacity

Tags: opacity, css

I have been playing with some CSS3 drop-shadow effects.  I am pretty fond of the "lifted corners" effect but I ran into an issue when attempting to add opacity to the element.  My question is:  Is there a way to create the "lifted corners" effect on an element with opacity?

http://jsfiddle.net/WAvZu/

```
.drop-shadow{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:40%;
    padding:1em;
    margin:2em 10px 4em;
    background:#fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}
.drop-shadow:before,
.drop-shadow:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-2;
}
.lifted{
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
}
.lifted:before,
.lifted:after{
    bottom:15px;
    left:10px;
    width:50%;
    height:20%;
    max-width:300px;
    max-height:100px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-3deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-3deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-3deg);
    transform:rotate(-3deg);
}
.lifted:after{
    right:10px;
    left:auto;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(3deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(3deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(3deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(3deg);
    transform:rotate(3deg);
}
```

Comment: An opaque element will create quite a complex shadow (try to hold a lens above a sheet of paper). IMO, this is the case when you should use an image, not CSS.

Comment: I would like to know the answer to this too.. but I'm afraid this is something impossible with css

Comment: Cool! Seems like a bug to me. Why else should `opacity` result in rendering the shadow on top?

Comment: I don't know. But I gotta say, that looks great!

Comment: @LinusCaldwell I dont think this is a bug, the background is losing opacity so you see the shadow beneath it

Comment: @DamienLegros, why should the `background` loose `opacity`? Try setting it to `0.2`, you'll see the shadow has a lower `opacity` too. On the other hand, with `0.999999` you see the shadow perfectly.

Comment: The shadow is not rendered on top. But as soon as you set some kind of opacity the shadow shines through the button because the shadow has a much better see-able color than the button itself. For sure when you set the opacity lower the shadow also looses strength in color but will ever be better to see than the button. Change your color schemes and you might be able to get a better solution. No bug here.

Comment: The question could be refined as "Why does opacity < 1 result in ignoring z-index on :before and :after?". Here is a [very simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/DMxTP/). Just set the `opacity` to `1`, and voila...

Comment: @SvenBieder, I really don't think this is true. See my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DMxTP/). The blue part does not show anything from the red. That's because `:before` and `:after` inherit the `opacity` like a child node would do, but the opacity between the nodes should not change unless you make the `background` transparent itself.

Comment: @LinusCaldwell http://jsfiddle.net/DMxTP/1/ here you can see that the z-index works like expected.

Comment: @SvenBieder, :-) it doesn't as far as I can tell. See this [update](http://jsfiddle.net/DMxTP/2/) which even does not use `:after`. Set the `opacity` to `< 1` and the black div comes to front (it is not slightly visible threw the red one, it is completely on top, tested with Firebug). Maybe I just don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Got it. It's no bug, it's specification.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is understanding [stacking contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context) and how they're rendered in the browser.

> - the root element (HTML),
> - positioned (absolutely or relatively) with a z-index value other than "auto",
> - elements with an [opacity value less than 1.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency)
> - on mobile WebKit and Chrome 22+, position: fixed always creates a new stacking context, even when z-index is "auto"

[9.9.1 Specifying the stack level: the 'z-index' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index)

> 1. the background and borders of the element forming the stacking
>      context.
> 2. the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most
>      negative first).
> 3. the in-flow, non-inline-level, non-positioned descendants.
> 4. the non-positioned floats.
> 5. the in-flow, inline-level, non-positioned descendants, including
>      inline tables and inline blocks.
> 6. the child stacking contexts with stack level 0 and the positioned
>      descendants with stack level 0.
> 7. the child stacking contexts with positive stack levels (least
>      positive first).

The background of `#test` is being rendered first since that is the element the opacity is being applied to. After that, the shadows go on top since they are in a new stacking context (`position: absolute`). And finally, the text of the div.

**A simple solution:** Would be to wrap the div in another div and apply the opacity to *that* div instead of the `#test`.

http://jsfiddle.net/WAvZu/3/

Another good read: [What No One Told You About Z-Index](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)

Answer (score 4):

After the discussion I'm not so sure about this to be honest, but I found this article: [The stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context).

As far as I know, the trick with `z-index: -2` in your example just works because you did not set a `z-index` on `.drop-shadow`, which means it has no stacking context. Normally a child (`:before` and `:after` is some sort of child too) cannot have a lower `z-index` than it's parent, but it can be below if the parent has no stacking context.

The problem with `opacity` is, that it forms stacking context:

> A stacking context is formed, anywhere in the document, by any element which is either
>
> - the root element (HTML),
> - positioned (absolutely or relatively) with a z-index value other than "auto",
> - elements with an opacity value less than 1. (...),
> - ...

With that said, you could [work around by using a wrapper](http://jsfiddle.net/s7p9p/)

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="drop-shadow lifted">This is correct with opacity.</div>
</div>
```

and set the `opacity` there.

```
.wrapper {
    opacity: .5;
}
```

Comment: Good find. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DMxTP/21/) demonstrates it better. Test 1 is two independent elements positioned having the same `.9` opacity as the Test 2 element which shows clearly the difference in rendering. The Test 3 element is nested like Test 2, but has an opacity of `1`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fake a solution to this by adding a `div` inside of the container with the "lifted corners".  It's a hack and I imagine that someone else could come up with a better solution but I thought I would post my findings in case anyone was curious.

http://jsfiddle.net/WAvZu/2/

Comment: Hey, just curious. Where did you get that background? `url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9z…0aD0iOTkiIGhlaWdodD0iMjUiIGZpbGw9IiNjZWU2OWIiPjwvcmVjdD4KPC9nPgo8L3N2Zz4=");` ?

Comment: @ChrisB Here is an SVG playground on CodePen.  http://codepen.io/progers/pen/IvHfd