# Box-shadow only on div corners

Tags: css

I have a problem with box-shadow. I need to have shadow only on bottom corners of div as on this image. Deos anyone know how to do that? Thanks in advance for your help.
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 "Lifted Corners" Drop-Shadow with Opacity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067109/css3-lifted-corners-drop-shadow-with-opacity)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i am sharing working link to the example.

You can do this using `css3`.

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hLruq/)

Comment: I tried this, but it's now visible until I give z-index:0 or higher. What can be a problem?

Comment: may be because you have other parent that has higher z-index assigned...share `HTML` and `CSS`

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-css selectors.

There's a good description and tutorial of the process here: [CSS Drop-shadows](http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/)

Demo of the effects here: [Demo page](http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/demo/)

If you're using SASS / SCSS head over [here](http://ahrengot.com/web-development/css-shadows-without-images/) to grab a mixin to automatically generate the effect for you.